# Office.js Excel: Call text to column excel function from javascript?

Tags: office-js, excel-2016

Inside Office.js in Excel 2016 how can I call Excel's text to column function from my javascript code?

Is this feature available yet in Office.js, or do I need to submit a feature request for it (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time, we don't have this API available yet.

So yes please log a feature request on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and we will consider it for future API release.

-Philip, Developer on the Office Extensibility team